# How can I do mansory style or something like this image area

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I'm using Bootstrap4. If I do responsive for mansory style gallery with img-fluid tag. For example, the second image is so long(as height) and there is a so much space with other images. How can I do this gallery like these for example tumblr or pexels.com ?

```
 <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/buffalo-nature-animals-animal-green.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://pixellous.imgix.net/animals/africa-african-animal-cat-41315.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/landscape-dark-view-nature.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/lifts-technology-lift-black-and-white.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/man-black-and-white-excited.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/spices-salt-pepper-spoon.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I did like the answer but I need lazy load on this. I've tried so much but I could do this together please help!

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

.masonry {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.item {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/buffalo-nature-animals-animal-green.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://pixellous.imgix.net/animals/africa-african-animal-cat-41315.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/landscape-dark-view-nature.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/lifts-technology-lift-black-and-white.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/man-black-and-white-excited.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/spices-salt-pepper-spoon.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure CSS version of responsive masonry, no plugin or script used.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

.masonry {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.item {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/buffalo-nature-animals-animal-green.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://pixellous.imgix.net/animals/africa-african-animal-cat-41315.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/landscape-dark-view-nature.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/lifts-technology-lift-black-and-white.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/man-black-and-white-excited.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/spices-salt-pepper-spoon.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help.!

Comment: How can I add this codes to lazyload org imgix.js ? If I enable lazyload everything going to ... you know :D

Answer (score 1):

Just add masonry to the page and configure it with `itemSelector: '.col-md-4'`

```js
$('.row').masonry(function() {
  itemSelector: '.col-md-4'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.1.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/buffalo-nature-animals-animal-green.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://pixellous.imgix.net/animals/africa-african-animal-cat-41315.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/landscape-dark-view-nature.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/lifts-technology-lift-black-and-white.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/man-black-and-white-excited.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/spices-salt-pepper-spoon.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to get rid of the horizontal padding in the cells that creates a gutter between the images, you could always just not use bootstrap `.col` classes there, or you can add `.nowrap` to the parent `.row` and remove the padding with CSS like `.nopad > div { padding: 0; }`

```js
$('.row').masonry(function() {
  itemSelector: '.col-md-4'
});
```

```css
.nopad > div {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.1.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="row nopad">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/buffalo-nature-animals-animal-green.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://pixellous.imgix.net/animals/africa-african-animal-cat-41315.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/landscape-dark-view-nature.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/lifts-technology-lift-black-and-white.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/man-black-and-white-excited.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/spices-salt-pepper-spoon.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you help man, How can I add this codes to lazyload org imgix.js ? If I enable lazyload everything going to ... you know :D