# How can I use LazyLoad with Mansory Style Image Gallery (Pure if it's possible)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Code is like that for mansory from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286417/7563953.
I tried every answer like this answer in SOF.
I'm trying to add lazyload (https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload or something like this framework for  wait to loading images until scrolldown) ons but I failled everytime. There is no force to pure mansory but I have to do lazy load because there is like 1000 images.  Is there anyone help me ?

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .masonry {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

.masonry {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}

.item {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/buffalo-nature-animals-animal-green.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://pixellous.imgix.net/animals/africa-african-animal-cat-41315.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/landscape-dark-view-nature.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/lifts-technology-lift-black-and-white.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/man-black-and-white-excited.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://d1p5m9g4zcqpp8.cloudfront.net/Photos/popular/spices-salt-pepper-spoon.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lazy load" exactly? Are you referring to a specific script/plugin or technique?

Comment: lazyload https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload or something like this framework for wait to loading images until scrolldown

Comment: did you try using it?

Comment: When i activate when loading new images images switching places when every images loading and mansory is going down